# Changing the css dynamically for a span inside a div in list itemTpl

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

Here is the thing I am stuck with:

```
Ext.define('Application.view.phone.AppScreen', {
extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',
//  extend: 'Ext.Container',
xtype: 'appscreen',
id: 'appscreen',
alias: 'widget.appscreen',
config: {

    items: [{
        xtype: 'container',
        title: 'My View',
        layout: {
            type: 'fit'
        },
        items:[{
            html:'phone'
        },

        {
            xtype:'list',
            id:'AccountSummary',
            name:'AccountSummary',
            onItemDisclosure:true,
            store:{
                fields: ['Label', 'Amount'],
                data: [
                {
                    "Label":"Order",
                    "Amount": "18,275"
                },

                {
                    "Label":"Shipment",
                    "Amount": "25,255"
                },

                {
                    "Label":"Invoices",
                    "Amount": "11,125"
                }
                ]
            }, 

        itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate('{Label}<tpl if="Label==Order"><div class="meter"><span style="width: 60%"></span></div></tpl><tpl if="Label==Shipment"><div class="meter1"><span style="width: 60%"></span></div></tpl><br>$ {Amount} Cash')

        }]
    }]
}
```

});

I need to change the css dynamically for example if the label is order I need to apply the css meter,similarly meter1 for Shipment.Can someone please help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fairly simple, take a look at my working TPL examle below:

```
new Ext.Container({
    fullscreen : true,
    tpl        : '<tpl if="foo == &quot;bar&quot;">Is Bar</tpl>',
    data       : {
        foo : 'bar'
    }
});
```

I think you just need to add encoded quotes to your statement since your checking a string, see the updated code below:

```
itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate('{Label}<tpl if="Label == &quot;Order&quot;"><div class="meter"><span style="width: 60%"></span></div></tpl><tpl if="Label == &quot;Shipment&quot;"><div class="meter1"><span style="width: 60%"></span></div></tpl><br>$ {Amount} Cash')
```